# Creating a Pareto Chart with ggplot2 and R

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have been struggling with how to make a [Pareto Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_chart) in R using the ggplot2 package. In many cases when making a bar chart or histogram we want items sorted by the X axis. In a Pareto Chart we want the items ordered descending by the value in the Y axis. Is there a way to get ggplot to plot items ordered by the value in the Y axis? I tried sorting the data frame first but it seems ggplot reorders them.

Example:

```
val <- read.csv("http://www.cerebralmastication.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/val.txt")
val<-with(val, val[order(-Value), ])
p <- ggplot(val)
p + geom_bar(aes(State, Value, fill=variable), stat = "identity", position="dodge") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

the data frame val is sorted but the output looks like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cerebralmastication.com](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/exp.png))</sub>

Hadley correctly pointed out that this produces a much better graphic for showing actuals vs. predicted:

```
ggplot(val, aes(State, Value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", subset = .(variable == "estimate"), fill = "grey70") + geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = Value, ymax = Value), subset = .(variable == "actual"))
```

which returns:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cerebralmastication.com](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/exp1.png))</sub>

But it's still not a Pareto Chart. Any tips?

Comment: You can do this with base graphics using the par(new) trick of overplotting -- same approach as for the usual 'chart with two y-axes' problem.  Ggplot2 I cannot help with (yet, one day maybe I get time to catch up on it).

Comment: I'm trying soooo hard to avoid learning base graphics. I'm fantastically lazy :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The bars in ggplot2 are ordered by the ordering of the levels in the factor.

```
val$State <- with(val, factor(val$State, levels=val[order(-Value), ]$State))
```

Comment: That is awesome! That's exactly what I could not figure out how to do. Thank you!

Comment: Or a little more succinctly, change your first aes call to: ` aes(reorder(State, Value), Value)`

Comment: I think you need aes(reorder(State, Value, mean), Value) - since there are two values for each state?

Answer (score 23):

Subsetting and sorting your data;

```
valact <- subset(val, variable=='actual')
valsort <- valact[ order(-valact[,"Value"]),]
```

From there it's just a standard `boxplot()` with a very manual cumulative function on top:

```
op <- par(mar=c(3,3,3,3)) 
bp <- barplot(valsort [ , "Value"], ylab="", xlab="", ylim=c(0,1),    
              names.arg=as.character(valsort[,"State"]), main="How's that?") 
lines(bp, cumsum(valsort[,"Value"])/sum(valsort[,"Value"]), 
      ylim=c(0,1.05), col='red') 
axis(4)
box() 
par(op)
```

which should look like this

[image]
<sub>(source: [eddelbuettel.com](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/misc/jdlong_pareto.png))</sub>

and it doesn't even need the overplotting trick as `lines()` happily annotates the initial plot.

Comment: I accepted Chang's answer because I really wanted to do this with ggplot. But I still owe you a beer for giving such a kick ass answer.

Comment: you gave a far more through answer to the Perato part than I was expecting! My question was grossly stylized and I had coded myself into a corner where using ggplot2 was the easiest way out. What you did with base graphics was really cool. Thanks again.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel -- as a crazy followup, I was wondering if you could modify your answer so that it accepts a facet_wrap?

Answer (score 7):

A traditional Pareto chart in ggplot2.......

Developed after reading
Cano, E. L., Moguerza, J. M., & Redchuk, A. (2012). Six Sigma with R. (G. Robert, K. Hornik, & G. Parmigiani, Eds.) Springer.

```
library(ggplot2);library(grid)

counts  <- c(80, 27, 66, 94, 33)
defects <- c("price code", "schedule date", "supplier code", "contact num.", "part num.")
dat <- data.frame(count = counts, defect = defects, stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
dat <- dat[order(dat$count, decreasing=TRUE),]
dat$defect <- factor(dat$defect, levels=dat$defect)
dat$cum <- cumsum(dat$count)
count.sum<-sum(dat$count)
dat$cum_perc<-100*dat$cum/count.sum

p1<-ggplot(dat, aes(x=defect, y=cum_perc, group=1))
p1<-p1 + geom_point(aes(colour=defect), size=4) + geom_path()

p1<-p1+ ggtitle('Pareto Chart')+ theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_blank())
p1<-p1+theme(legend.position="none")

p2<-ggplot(dat, aes(x=defect, y=count,colour=defect, fill=defect))
p2<- p2 + geom_bar()

p2<-p2+theme(legend.position="none")

plot.new()
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 1)))
print(p1, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1,layout.pos.col = 1))
print(p2, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2,layout.pos.col = 1))
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use the `ggQC` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggQC)
Data4Pareto <- data.frame(
  KPI = c("Customer Service Time", "Order Fulfillment", "Order Processing Time",
          "Order Production Time", "Order Quality Control Time", "Rework Time",
          "Shipping"),
  Time = c(1.50, 38.50, 3.75, 23.08, 1.92, 3.58, 73.17)) 


ggplot2::ggplot(Data4Pareto, aes(x = KPI, y = Time)) +
 ggQC::stat_pareto(point.color = "red",
                   point.size = 3,
                   line.color = "black",
                   bars.fill = c("blue", "orange")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

[Source](https://r-bar.net/ggqc-ggplot-quality-control-charts/)

Answer (score 4):

With a simple example:

```
 > data
    PC1     PC2     PC3     PC4     PC5     PC6     PC7     PC8     PC9    PC10 
0.29056 0.23833 0.11003 0.05549 0.04678 0.03788 0.02770 0.02323 0.02211 0.01925
```

`barplot(data)` does things correctly

the ggplot equivalent "should be": `qplot(x=names(data), y=data, geom='bar')`

But that incorrectly reorders/sorts the bars alphabetically... because that's how `levels(factor(names(data)))` would be ordered.

Solution: `qplot(x=factor(names(data), levels=names(data)), y=data, geom='bar')`

Phew!

Answer (score 3):

Also, see the package [qcc](http://cran.r-project.org/package=qcc) which has a function `pareto.chart()`.  Looks like it uses base graphics too, so start your bounty for a ggplot2-solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

To simplify things, let's just consider only the estimates.

```
estimates <- subset(val, variable == "estimate")
```

First we reorder the factor levels, so that `State`s are plotted in decreasing order of `Value`.

```
estimates$State <- with(estimates, reorder(State, -Value))
```

Similarly, we reorder the dataset and calculate a cumulative value.

```
estimates <- estimates[order(estimates$Value, decreasing = TRUE),]
estimates$cumulative <- cumsum(estimates$Value)
```

Now we are ready to draw the plot.  The trick to get a line and bar on the same axes is to convert the State variable (a factor) to be numeric.

```
p <- ggplot(estimates, aes(State, Value)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  geom_line(aes(as.numeric(State), cumulative))
p
```

As mentioned in the question, trying to draw two Pareto plots of two variable groups right next to each other isn't very easy.  You'd probably be better off using facetting if you want multiple Pareto plots.

Answer (score 0):

```
freqplot = function(x, by = NULL, right = FALSE)
{
if(is.null(by)) stop('Valor de "by" precisa ser especificado.')
breaks = seq(min(x), max(x), by = by )
ecd = ecdf(x)
den = ecd(breaks)
table = table(cut(x, breaks = breaks, right = right))
table = table/sum(table)

intervs = factor(names(table), levels = names(table))
freq = as.numeric(table/sum(table))
acum = as.numeric(cumsum(table))

normalize.vec = function(x){
  (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))
}

dados = data.frame(classe = intervs, freq = freq, acum = acum, acum_norm = normalize.vec(acum))
p = ggplot(dados) + 
  geom_bar(aes(classe, freq, fill = classe), stat = 'identity') +
  geom_point(aes(classe, acum_norm, group = '1'), shape = I(1), size = I(3), colour = 'gray20') +
  geom_line(aes(classe, acum_norm, group = '1'), colour = I('gray20'))

p
}
```